# Does material bootstrap provides responsiveness to all components or utilities?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries, bootstrap-4

I am new to bootstrap and started following their docs. Meanwhile I also started writing one web app and keeps checking for the responsiveness with the chrome's developer tool. I used their button components and started testing the responsiveness.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary"><i class="fa fa-sign-in" aria-hidden="true"></i>SIGN IN</button>
```

And this line is also in the `head` tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
```

But I am unable to receive the responsiveness with this button. After following few posts seems like I can achieve that using media query in which I have to assign the components dimensions for each and every screen.
Does bootstrap provides the responsiveness to all of their components or utilities ? If no then what are those components or utilities I have to write the media query. If yes then am I missing something here ?

This is the normal view
[image]

You can see there is a sidebar. And while testing this is how it's looking like

[image]

The sidebar is hidden now.
**psst!**This is in fixed navbar
**Code :**

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
            <ul class="navbar-nav flex-row ml-md-auto d-none d-md-flex">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary"><i class="fa fa-sign-in" aria-hidden="true"></i>Sign In</button>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary"><i class="fa fa-registered" aria-hidden="true"></i>Register a property</button>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <img src="img/sidebar.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Sidebar navigation">
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: what do you expect a button to become in responsive mode. please clarify.

Comment: It should shrink with respect to screen. Currently I am losing some information and some views with this button

Comment: would you be able to share a screenshot or fiddle, codepen?

Comment: @Johnsackson post edited

Comment: First thought: If you add custom elements/styles even if you use bootstrap, it will not handle the responsiveness. For instance if you say padding: 20px to a button, it still remains 20px in mobile screens as well. The point is for custom styles you must write appropriate media query styles to it.

Comment: I didn't add a single line of custom style

Comment: I'm sure there are custom styles overriding in your page. Coz if you create a navigation bar/button in bootstrap(without custom styles) it would look like this. https://codepen.io/johnsackson/pen/NMGMmz .
Try resizing this.

Comment: I am sure there are no custom styles. My css file is empty right now and there is no inline styling

Comment: Can you share your code please

Comment: I added the code. Just tried your code as well and added few bootstrap material icons and an image. Still the same problem. This time the button are not visible after a certain dimensions

Comment: Maybe it's local? Have you tried with other browser?

Comment: @A.Meshu how does it matter if it's local ? I can understand with respect to browser

Comment: @Lokesh Need the full code, as in complete html with any css

Comment: @Johnsackson As said there is no custom style added. Yes I downloaded the bootstrap material design from here https://mdbootstrap.com/getting-started/ and doing my development

Comment: Ok, good luck with that!

Comment: As you know the material bootstrap(the one that you're using) is built over bootstrap(http://getbootstrap.com). They've modified the styles to improve visual feel such as padding, box-shadow, animations etc. To cope with that you must add media queries of your own(for handheld devices). I would suggest use plain bootstrap instead. It gives you more control over things.

Comment: @Johnsackson I can use plain bootstrap. The reason why I downloaded the material design bootstrap is because to use their icons and also other effects which you mentioned earlier. If I use plain bootstrap I don't know how would I use the material design with xampp or the local server. There are ways of installing it but all come up with node packages which I am not doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it to shrink when the screen shrinks set it's width using either percentage values or `vw`

for example if the button is within a div that has 100% width and you set it to 20% width it will take up 1/5 of the screen.

```
div{
  width: 100%;
}

div .btn{
 width: 20%
}

<div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary"><i class="fa fa-sign-in" aria-hidden="true"></i>SIGN IN</button>
</div>
```

This has nothing to do with material bootstrap, this is just basic CSS.

Bootstrap does, however, [provide a grid system and built-in breakpoints to help with responsive design](https://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#grid-tiers)

Comment: @Lokesh thanks for accepting my answer, please upvote it if it's helped you